# How to redirect a site to a new site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site which has pages like this:

```
blabla.com/page/whatever
blabla.com/category/whatever
blabla.com/about
...
```

How can I redirect each of these to a new domain, like:

```
blabla.net/page/whatever
blabla.net/category/whatever
blabla.net/about
...
```

?

Using .htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive:

```
Redirect / http://blabla.net/
```

This directive automatically preserves anything specified after the `/`.

Answer (score 1):

It might take a bit of fiddling, but the basic idea should work here:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://blabla.net/$1 [R,NC]
```

You need to have mod_rewrite installed in Apache.

This says "match all URLs on this site, and redirect them to `http://blabla.net/the same URL`. The [R] means to actually send a redirect request to the client (so the client will make the request to the new server), rather than just serving up the page but keeping the browser URL the same. You can take the R out if you just want to serve the page but keep the old URL.

Comment: Hmm.. looks like Greg's answer is a more direct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you use nginx (like we at http://applehub.us, http://crazyfootball.net etc)

```
location ~ ^/.*_sitemap([\d]+)?.(xml|xml.gz)$ {
  rewrite /(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://yourupstrem;
}
```